# Sencha touch Textfield hightlight behavior in Samsung Galaxy Tab

Tags: css, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, galaxy-tab

While editing any textfield/textareafield in Sencha touch, the text field gets highlighted or focussed. This behavior is causing too many issues. The loading indicator and Alert appears behind the highlighted textfield as the text field remains focussed.
This behavior is seen only in Samsung Galaxy Tab. The app behaves fine on iPad.
Please let me know if it is possible to remove this highlighting effect.

Answer (score 0):

Solution CSS:

```
input[type="text"], input[type="password"]{
 -webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only;
 -webkit-user-select:text;
 -moz-user-select:-moz-text;
 -moz-user-select:text;
}
```