# Sencha Touch Panel Scrollability issue in Android tablets

Tags: css, html, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have a panel in Sencha touch which shows some htm file.

```
 Ext.define('Project.view.eula.EulaPanel',{
extend:'Ext.Panel',
requires: ['Ext.Ajax','Ext.Panel'],
xtype:'eulaPanel',  
id:'eulaPanel',
config:
{
    scrollable:true,
    padding:10,
     listeners: {
            activate: 'onActivate'
        },

        // Create a new configuration called `url` so we can specify the URL
    url: 'resources/eula/EULA.htm',
    items:[
         {
             xtype:'toolbar',
             docked:'top',
             items:[
                    {
                        xtype:'button',
                        text:'Accept',
                        action:'eulaAcceptBtn',
                    },
                    {
                        xtype:'button',
                        text:'Decline',
                        action:'eulaDeclineBtn',
                    },


                    ]

         }


        ]

},
onActivate: function(eulaPanel, container) {
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: this.getUrl(),
        method: "GET",
        success: function(response, request) {
            eulaPanel.setHtml(response.responseText);
        },
        failure: function(response, request) {
            eulaPanel.setHtml("failed -- response: " + response.responseText);
        }
    });
}
});
```

This panel is the first panel that gets displayed when the app is opened. But it cannot be scrolled. If you navigate to any other page or reopen the app again the panel becomes scrollable. Please let me know if anyone knows the fix.

Answer (score 0):

Just try setting scrollable config in Panel as follows instead of true

```
scrollable : {
      direction     : 'vertical'
 }
```

Comment: Viswa : Do you have any idea about it??

Comment: Can you test one thing?. comment the ajax request and hard code the html in panel using html config.. now test the app.

Comment: The html content is huge. I cannot put it inside panel as there are many " ' quotes in between

Comment: ya understood. is it a continues text or number of paragraph and is it scrolling horizontally ?

Comment: Just put just 2 line of html with scrollable:true.. and test.. is it scrolling vertical?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31998/discussion-between-akshatha-and-viswa)

Comment: I don't know why it's not woking for you.. but for the interest i test in lg optimus p970.. its woking... scrollbar is woking as i saw in chrome..

Comment: i am very desperate to solve this problem, but i can't find the problem as you saying.. anyway if you have time update the question with LoginMain panel.. i will check that later

Comment: Can you please look at this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17184095/sencha-touch-textfield-hightlight-behavior-in-samsung-galaxy-tab